# context.drawImage for multiple images eventually causes FireFox to Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, canvas

I am creating an Image Uploader which should be able to accept at least 1000 images. Once the user chooses/drag-drop the images, images should be displayed for previewing purpose. Then, user will click on Upload Button to initiate the upload.

I have implemented the whole functionality and it works on Chrome like a charm. But this fails in Firefox.

I have created a queuing mechanism in such a way that at a point of time only n number of images will be getting loaded in the browser once a user chooses the images.

Also crash happens for more than 20 images(even if create a batch of 1 image using the queuing mechanism). I have checked the memory usage using Tab Memory Usage Plugin(http://mybrowseraddon.com/tab-memory.html) in Firefox. It even crashes for memory utilization of 40 MB. So I guess, it is not because of any memory leak.

```
function readAndDisplay(file, index){
    id = getFileId(file);
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        addImageCard(file, index);
        resizeImage(e, index);
        delete this;
        //$('#image' + id).attr('src', e.target.result);

    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function resizeImage(fileReaderEvent, index){

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("image" + index);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        img.src = "";
        delete canvas;
        delete ctx;
        img = null;
        delete fileReaderEvent;

        uploadQueue.push(index);
        if(loadImageIterator < updatedFiles.length){
            loadImage(updatedFiles[loadImageIterator++]);
        }
        else{
            updatedFiles = [];
        }

    }
    img.src = fileReaderEvent.target.result;
    var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(fileReaderEvent.target.result).toString();
    console.log(md5);
}

function addImageCard(file, index){

    imageHolder = $("#imageholder");

    imageCard = $("<div>", {
        class: "col m1 s4",
        id: "card" + index
    });

    innerDiv = $("<div>", {
        class: "card"
    });

    cardImage = $("<div>", {
        class: "card-image",
    }).append($("<canvas>", {
        id: "image" + index,
        css: {
            width: "100%"
        }
        //src: "images/sample-1.jpg"
    })).append($("<span>", {
        class: "card-title",
        text: ""
    }));

    cardContent = $("<div>",{
        class: "card-content",
        html: "<p>" + file.name + "</p>"
    });

    cardAction = $("<div>", {
        class: "card-action"
    });

    removeButton = $("<a>", {
        title: "Remove",
        css: {
            "font-size": "20px"
        },
        click: function(){
            remove(index)
        }

    }).append($("<span>", {
        class: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"
    }));

    uploadButton = $("<a>", {
        title: "Upload Now",
        css: {
            "font-size": "20px",
            float: "right",
            "margin-right": "4px"
        }

    }).append($("<span>", {
        class: "glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"
    }));

    cardAction.append(removeButton);
    cardAction.append(uploadButton);

    innerDiv.append(cardImage);
    innerDiv.append(cardContent);
    innerDiv.append(cardAction);
    imageCard.append(innerDiv);
    imageHolder.append(imageCard);

}
```

When I comment following code, Firefox doesn't crashes
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)

So I have figured so far that the issue is with this drawImage. Probably the implementation of drawImage is different in Chrome and Firefox and the way I am using it makes it work in Chrome but with Firefox, it throws an error.

Does anyone has any concrete idea as to why this issue is happening?

JSFiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/sanchit235/7xh1gbj6/

Firefox Crash Report- https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/6107c530-12a1-4aea-96c9-0366c2151010

Comment: `delete` doesn't do what you're thinking it does. It only removes properties from objects and doesn't remove object references (so the garbage collector won't reclaim the object's memory).

Comment: Delete has little or no significance here. I have added it just to be sure. All the variables here are local. So, they would be garbage collected by themselves ideally. If some of them are bound to cause leak because of the way I am using them, please do let me know.

Comment: Does it also happens when you don't do all this useless cleaning?

Comment: It is happening even if I am doing this useless cleaning ;)
Btw, without this useless cleaning, chrome was giving Aww Snap. So I was forced to do it.

Comment: That doesn't seem a correct solution for your "aw snap" problem to me. If my believe that it occurs because your code makes the page unresponsive is correct, maybe you could give `requestAnimationFrame` throtteling a try. I have no time right now to even reproduce the error so I can't tell if it would work but it should give time to the browser to handle every objects and garbage collecting as it should.

Comment: Memory for my tab was going to as high as 2GB and was not reducing once/if all the images got loaded. So I guess, in this case Aww Snap was because of some memory leak. With this cleaning, the memory is not even exceeding 700MB and gets reduced to around 200MB once all the images have been loaded. Also requestAnimationFrame didn't solve the problem. Besides as far as I know, requestAnimationFrame is used for animations. I don't understand why should we use it here?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` does ask the browser to do our calculations when it is ready to do it. It can also be used to perform a batch of heavy operations, without blocking the execution process (to give your browser a breath).

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems in your code :

- First one is that you called synchronously `loadImage()` in a for loop in the `FileSelectHandler()` (onchange) which itself called back `loadImage()`asynchronously once the drawing was done if the loop didn't finished (on my comp it occurs 15 times for 20 images).
  Calling it only once onchange and letting the asynchronous callback is enough.
- Second one is in the check for callback :
  `if(loadImageIterator < updatedFiles.length){
     loadImage(updatedFiles[loadImageIterator++]);
    }`
  should be replaced with
  `if(++loadImageIterator < updatedFiles.length){
     loadImage(updatedFiles[loadImageIterator]);
    }`
  or the first call will pass `updatedFiles[0]`.
- Third one is your variable declarations. You forgot the `var` before `reader`, `newFile` and a few other ones, making those global variables.

Here is the [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xh1gbj6/3/) which doesn't throw any error in Chrome nor FF, without deleting anything by yourself.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, My FF is crashing for your fiddle but Chrome works fine. Can you check if your FF also crashes for the fiddle that I have added with same image set that you have tried with your fiddle.

Comment: @SanchitMehta No, I never was able to reproduce your FF crash from the fiddle you gave, even with 40*5MB pictures. Have you got a message in the console before the crash ? Have you tried loading every images one by one to see if one of the file could be the cause ? Is your FF updated ?

Comment: I did try loading 1 image at a time. Try with 300*5 MB images. I am sure you will see the error. Also in IE11, the script stops executing after some time(probably, the browser detects this and stops the script that may eventually crash IE). Also, now I have removed the useless delete statements and added var before each initialization(initially I was doing the same), there is no memory leak. I wonder, why it was there earlier.
Try this- 
http://www.dropzonejs.com/
They are also doing pretty much what I am doing and for them as well FF crashes :D

Comment: @SanchitMehta just did with 900 calls, no crash, fans spin a little faster though. But I am on a mac, with 16GB RAM, maybe your conf has a problem, can you repro on another device? Also, your code is fixed, your crash comes from something else now. Fill a bug to bugzilla if you'd like so.